# Why doesn't the U.K. just revoke its Article 50 withdrawal?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, article-50

Appreciating that it would be extremely politically unpopular, are there any policy reasons why a PM wouldn't just revoke the withdrawal, unilaterally cancelling Brexit?

Comment: The UK portends to be a democratic country, or atleast attempts some of the more popular aspects of democratic countries. Such an action to effectively revoke a democratic result as the referendum would be seen as autocratic and perhaps even dictatorial. At a minimum, it would be grossly hypocritical. Even if by some political miracle it was allowed to happen, or even more likely rebuked, there would be no faith by the UK citizenry in the democratic process again. It would essentially become null and void. I don't think the UK government is willing to go that far, even for Brexit.

Comment: @ouflak A _Non binding_ referendum remember.  If May wanted to she could withdraw Article 50.  It's been a weird few years - "Boaty McBoatface" - Don't be stupid we're overruling you.  "Nuke the economy from orbit" - The people's will must be respected.

Comment: @mcottle, Correct. A non-binding referendum. Like I said, the UK portends to be a democracy. That doesn't mean they are. The PM unilaterally going against the will of the referendum would remove any pretense on that point. Unfortunately, I'm not too clear on your references, but these assumptions that all sorts of extreme terrible things will happen reminds me of the Y2K hysteria. In some cases, the wording is exactly the same. I wonder if/when people will start to come to their senses and realise that things probably won't be so bad.  It's entertaining. Maybe a sci-fi movie is in the works?

Comment: @ouflak, while the referendum was non-binding, since then there has been Brexit *legislation*. Can the PM override that without help from parliament? Regarding democracy in the UK, I think you're doing them an injustice. Brexit is a "how much" question and not a "yes or no" question and those are notoriously unsuitable for a referendum.

Comment: @ouflak I remember the Y2K predictions, and the huge amount of work by competent specialists to fix it. It was also an entirely uncontroversial solution. Brexit has no obvious solutions and no competence deployed, which is why every single person familiar with project management and logistics is worried about it. It's the Fyre Festival of international trade.

Comment: @pjc50. Bit off-topic (my fault), but what I meant was the wild predictions of every sort of nearly unbelievable catastrophe or side effect that might occur. In fairness, you can just now start seeing a rare few more reasonable articles creep up that are more objective, suggesting that things won't actually be so bad. But that's the same thing that began to happen in the Y2K hysteria as the date came closer and reality started to set in. I predict the same with no-deal Brexit. I (and I'm sure others) appreciate the 'competent specialists' designation ;-) .

Comment: @ouflak reports are circulating of people told that their radiotherapy will be delayed due to the lack of agreement on Euratom. No-deal Brexit *will* get a few people killed at the margin, but then this already happens with Universal Credit and the disability benefit situation.

Comment: @pjc50, There was an article a few days ago that stated that the divorce rate would rise due to No-deal Brexit. https://www.aol.co.uk/living/2019/01/24/the-surprise-impact-a-no-deal-brexit-could-have-on-marriages/?guccounter=1. See if you can top that.

Comment: @ouflak seems not implausible on the face of it - it is stressful, people are losing their jobs, and marriages between EU and UK citizens will be coming under significant strain. Mind you, your source is AOL..

Comment: @pjc50, Well we'll see what kind of articles are dominating the newsscape when we're under 2 weeks to go, assuming nothing else changes ofcourse. In any case, I don't think there can be a unilateral revokation of Article 50 by the Prime Minister, but who knows? She's seems so out of touch that she might just actually believe she can get away with it (and she *might* be right). I think the dystopian 'not implausible' predictions will soon reach an apex (if they haven't already) and eventually subside.

Comment: @ouflak portend means to presage or foreshadow.  For example, "these clouds portend a heavy rainstorm."  Did you perhaps mean "purport," or indeed "pretend"?

Comment: @phoog, I meant to use the word because I am implying that they are constantly giving hints of democracy at different points in history, and even perhaps now, and that they might yet prove to be. They occassionally actually behave similar to one, such as having elections and referendums. If strictly an appearance, then the proper word is 'purport'. If it is 'pretend', then why have elections or referendums with real results? If the UK exits the EU on March 29th, 2019, especially with no deal, then I will have no need for any such words. They *are* a democracy and will have demonstrated that.

Comment: @phoog, To be honest, even though I've lived in the UK for so many years now, I'm still not used to what they call 'democracy'. Coming from America, I'm used to direct election of individuals and very specific laws being voted on. I struggle to wrap my head around the idea that you are voting for a 'party' and really have no idea who your specific representative might be. Yet they preach "democracy" to the world. So maybe it's a democracy, just a different flavor. Come March 29th of this year, I'll have a better idea on if they are just teasing me and the rest of the world on that.

Comment: @ouflak portend is a transitive verb, but you are using it intransitively.  It really doesn't make any sense as you are using it.  My assumption about that you meant to say appears to have been incorrect, but after your explanation I am even less certain what word would be appropriate here.  You also appear to be describing the UK parliament as a proportional representation system, which it is not. UK constituencies do indeed elect individual candidates.

Comment: @phoog, That's the closest word I could find for what I meant. Are there no mods here? Very strange having these kind of conversations here in comments. I feel a little funny, probably coming from my StackOverflow background. I really don't want to get very off-topic. Is this sort of thing normal for Politics.Exchange? I'm still feeling my way around here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The decision to revoke the Article 50 notification would have to be [unequivocal and unconditional](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-46481643) and it would have to follow the democratic process according to UK constitutional requirements.

Given the various Brexit laws, it might be interpreted as unconstitutional if the PM unilaterally revokes the notification. Lawyers and courts would have to rule on that, possibly both in the UK *and* in the EU.

Currently there seems to be a majority in the UK for a Brexit, just no majority for any one Brexit model. The legal situation would become rather muddled if they re-declare an Article 50 notification after this *unequivocal and unconditional* revocation.

Comment: The legal case you cite is probably the only one where the UK government argued that the EU should not allow it to do something. "Take back control..."

Comment: I hope I live long enough to read the declassified Cabinet papers of this omnishambles.  I really would like to know what the government has actually been trying to achieve for the last month or two.

Comment: @mcottle, best case for their reputation would be if they tried brinksmanship to get more out of the EU. More likely, *there was no plan* other than staying in power day by day.

Comment: @o.m. Who actually thinks that the EU has any vested interest in the UK having a smooth Brexit?  If the UK's going "everything's fine outside" what does that mean the next time the PIIGS get in a financial pickle?  The EU want the UK to implode painfully "pour encourager les autres"

Comment: @mcottle, the EU has a vested interest in **Ireland** having a smooth Brexit. Or France and Belgium for that matter. But not at the cost of compromising the nature of the EU. *In means in and out means out.* A hard or bad Brexit is going to hurt the EU, but it will hurt the UK even more. A desperate UK negotiator might see that as potential leverage to pressure the EU. "Give me what I want or I'll hurt both of us."

Comment: @mcottle to read the papers now, follow Boris Johnson around and fish them out of bins: https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/politics/boris-johnson-dumps-brexit-parliamentary-13944587 ; and om is correct, the EU has no interest in the UK collapsing but it's not going to compromise its principles unless absolutely necessary. Always remember that Grexit never happened.